# Redireccionar a un route:group

Tags: laravel

Estoy por medio de un `middleware` redireccionando a mis usuarios dependiendo del rol a un grupo de rutas, lo que pasa es que no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, así tengo mi `middleware`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->rol=='admin')
            return $next($request);

        return abort(401);
    }
```

Tengo en mi web.php un grupo de rutas de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/Administrador',function(){
    return view ('administrador.administrador');
    })->name('administrador');
    Route::resource('usuarios','crudLaboratorios');
    Route::resource('lab','crudLab');

    // Route for view/blade file.
    Route::get('importExportView', 'TestController@importExportView')->name('importExportView');
    // Route for export/download tabledata to .csv, .xls or .xlsx
    Route::get('exportExcel/{type}', 'TestController@exportExcel')->name('exportExcel');
    // Route for import excel data to database.
    Route::post('importExcel', 'TestController@importExcel')->name('importExcel');

    //------------------------
    Route::get('/import','TestController@import');
});
```

Lo que pasa es que no se como en el middleware en la parte del return redireccionar al grupo de rutas especifico ya que pienso hacer muchos if porque son 23 rol y cada rol tendra un grupo de rutas. Intente poniendole al final del grupo de rutas `->name('nombre')` Pero me salia el siguiente error:

```
Call to a member function name() on null
```

Alguna forma de solucionar esto? O me tocaria crear 23 middleware para cada rol?

Comment: Elimina entonces la otrta pregunta por favor ya que sería un duplicado

Comment: @Aprendiz Ya lo hice, disculpa

Comment: A ver si entiendo... ¿intentas enviar a los admin a algo como `/admin/ruta` y digamos a los editores a `/editor/ruta` y así sucesivamente con 23 roles?

Comment: @Shaz si correcto